# CSS: Custom check box not working

Tags: html, css, checkbox, input

I have a basic custom check box and I need the box to change state to checked on click of the box but its not working. Can someone please help me to find out the problem?

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  display: block;
  content: "☐";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before {
  content: "☑";
}
```

```html
<lable for='product-45-45'>
  <input type='checkbox' style="float:right;"/>
  <div class="accord-text">
    <strong>header:</strong> sub text
    <strong>more text!</strong>
  </div>
</lable>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9o0csh9u/ -  working here. Fixed label and id mapping

Comment: my own, i got the idea from a example but have built my own from the idea

Comment: @RahulB nice fiddle thanks +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must *link* your `label` (note that it is misspelled *lable* in question) *for* with the `input` *id* for it to work - see demo below:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  display: block;
  content: "☐";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: green;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before {
  content: "☑";
}
```

```html
<label for='product-45-45'>
  <input type='checkbox' style="float:right;" id='product-45-45'/>
  <div class="accord-text">
    <strong>header:</strong> sub text
    <strong>more text!</strong>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

Make following two corrections in your code:

1. You are using misspelled `HTML` tags.

   ```
   <lable for='product-45-45'>
       ^^^ Check spelling here. Must be <label>
   ```
2. You forgot to add `id` to the `input` element connected with `label`.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  display: block;
  content: "☐";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before {
  content: "☑";
}
```

```html
<label for='product-45-45'>
  <input type='checkbox' id="product-45-45" style="float:right;"/>
  <div class="accord-text">
    <strong>header:</strong> sub text
    <strong>more text!</strong>
  </div>
</label>
```